# Image rendering using async storage, variables not ready

Tags: typescript, react-native

I have an issue with this React Native project where when this page loads in the app, I get the following error: `source.uri should not be an empty string`. It loops round a couple more times, and the console.log statements eventually evaluate to have values instead of empty strings. URL first, then followed by score. How would I ensure that the app has the values ready before the return?

```
import {Image, Text, View} from 'react-native';
import {useNavigation} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {StackNavigationProp} from '@react-navigation/stack';
import {RootStackParamList} from './RootStack';
import Styles from '../styles/MatchFoundStyles';
import {
  GestureHandlerRootView,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';

import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

type FingerScreenProp = StackNavigationProp<RootStackParamList, 'Fingerprint'>;

const MatchFound = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation<FingerScreenProp>();
  const [value, setValue] = useState('value');

  const useAsyncStorage = (key: string) => {
    const [storedData, setStoredData] = useState('');

    const storeData = async () => {
      try {
        const valueToStore =
          typeof value === 'string' ? value : JSON.stringify(value);
        await AsyncStorage.setItem(key, valueToStore);
        setStoredData(valueToStore);
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
      }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
      const getData = async () => {
        try {
          const storageValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key);
          if (storageValue !== null) {
            setStoredData(storageValue);
          }
        } catch (e) {
          console.error(e);
        }
      };
      getData();
    }, [key]);

    return {storedData, storeData};
  };

  const url = useAsyncStorage('@data__url').storedData;
  const score = useAsyncStorage('@data__score').storedData;

  console.log('Score =', score);
  console.log('URL =', url);

  return (
    <GestureHandlerRootView style={Styles.container}>
      <View style={Styles.container}>
        <View>
          <Image style={{height: 100, width: 100}} source={{uri: url}} />
        </View>
      </View>
    </GestureHandlerRootView>
  );
};

export default MatchFound;
```

Answer (score 0):

> How would I ensure that the app has the values ready before the return?

Since getting the value is asynchronous, it is impossible to have it ready on the first render of the same component that is in charge of fetching the value. There will always be one render with no data, then a delay, then you set state with the new data. You have a couple options for dealing with this:

1. Have the component check for the empty value, and modify its behavior. For example, you could skip rendering the image, or render a placeholder until the loading is complete:

```
// ...
<View>
  {url ? <Image style={{height: 100, width: 100}} source={{uri: url}} /> : null}
</View>
```

2. Split the component into two components; have one of the component deal with the loading, and the other component only get rendered once the url exists

```
const DataLoader = () => {
  const url = useAsyncStorage('@data__url').storedData;
  const score = useAsyncStorage('@data__score').storedData;

  if (url && score) {
    return <MatchFound url={url} score={score}/>
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}

const MatchFound = ({ url, score }) => {
  const navigation = useNavigation<FingerScreenProp>();
  // ...

}
```

Comment: The first solution doesn't work, as it complains, saying it needs to be rendered within a Text component.

Comment: Updated my answer to account for the fact that url is an empty string, not null or undefined.